# Python Mypy attribute error

Tags: python, mypy

I have a python3.4 project and I recently decided to use mypy for better understanding.

This chunk of code works but checking with mypy pops out an error :

```
import zipfile

def zip_to_txt(zip: typing.IO[bytes]) -> BytesIO:
zz = zipfile.ZipFile(zip)
output = BytesIO()
for line, info in enumerate(zz.filelist):
    date = "%d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d" % info.date_time[:6]
    output.write(str.encode("%-46s %s %12d\n" % (info.filename, date, info.file_size)))
output.seek(0, 0)
return output
```

The error :

`PyPreviewGenerator/file_converter.py:170: error: "ZipFile" has no attribute "filelist"`  (corresponds to this line : `for line, info in enumerate(zz.filelist):`)

But when I look inside the ZipFile class, I can clearly see that the attribute exists. 
So why does the error occurs ? and is there a way I can resolve it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, the reason is because the `filelist` attribute is not documented within Typeshed, the collection of type stubs for the stdlib/various 3rd party libraries. You can see this for yourself [here](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/master/stdlib/2and3/zipfile.pyi).

Why is `filelist` not included? Well, because it doesn't actually appear to be a [documented part of the API](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html). If you search through the document, you'll see `filelist` is not mentioned anywhere.

Instead, you should call the [`infolist()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.infolist), which returns exactly what you want (see [implementation here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/zipfile.py#L1249) if you're curious). You'll notice `infolist()` *is* indeed [listed within typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/master/stdlib/2and3/zipfile.pyi#L31).

Comment: Thank you, I did not know that it needs to be used as it is documented to work with mypy.